# Razor webgrid sorting not working if grid is loaded using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, webgrid

This is my code

```
  WebGrid passiveAdGrid = new WebGrid(Model.InactiveAds, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "passiveAdGrid");

    <div >
        @passiveAdGrid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
        @passiveAdGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "passiveAdGrid" },
                columns: passiveAdGrid.Columns(
                        passiveAdGrid.Column(format: @<text><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/preview-photo.gif")" alt="Image"/></text>),
                        passiveAdGrid.Column("Title", "Title", canSort: true),
                        passiveAdGrid.Column("ExpirationDate", "Date of Expiry", canSort: true),
                        passiveAdGrid.Column("NumViews", "Number of views", canSort: true),
                        passiveAdGrid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Activate", "PostAd", "Ads", new { relist = item.Id }, null)),
                        passiveAdGrid.Column(format: (item) => @Ajax.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveAd", "Ads", new { adID = item.Id, status = "ActivationPending" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AdView", HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Ad?');" }))
    ));
    </div>
```

its works fine if the above code is executed while page first time  loading ...

In my case I am loading this grid using ajax (ie,calling a action in cotroller which return a partial view  via ajax and replace that resulting html with existing html)... But sorting is not working anymore after relaoding the grid using ajax